# How to refresh TreeGrid in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, gxt, treegrid

Hello friend I am developing a GWT app, where I am using TreeGrid. When I use regular grid like in this mine class:

```
RpcProxy<ListLoadResult<GwtDatastoreAsset>> proxy = new RpcProxy<ListLoadResult<GwtDatastoreAsset>>() {

            @Override
            protected void load(Object loadConfig, AsyncCallback<ListLoadResult<GwtDatastoreAsset>> callback) {
                if (selectedDevice != null) {
                dataService.findAssets((LoadConfig) loadConfig, currentSession.getSelectedAccount().getId(), selectedDevice, callback);
                }
            }
        };

        loader = new BaseListLoader<ListLoadResult<GwtDatastoreAsset>>(proxy);
        loader.load();
        SwappableListStore<GwtDatastoreAsset> store = new SwappableListStore<GwtDatastoreAsset>(loader);
        assetGrid = new Grid<GwtDatastoreAsset>(store, new ColumnModel(configs));
        assetGrid.setBorders(false);
        assetGrid.setStateful(false);
        assetGrid.setLoadMask(true);
        assetGrid.setStripeRows(true);
        assetGrid.getView().setAutoFill(true);
        assetGrid.getView().setEmptyText(MSGS.assetTableEmptyText());
        assetGrid.disableTextSelection(false);
```

In this class in my refresh method I just do assetGrid.getStore().getLoader().load(); 
and that is it but with TreeGrid I cant do like that. This is my method with TreeGrid:

```
 AsyncCallback<List<GwtTopic>> topicsCallback = new AsyncCallback<List<GwtTopic>>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<GwtTopic> topics) {
                store.add(topics, true);
                topicInfoGrid.unmask();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                FailureHandler.handle(t);
                topicInfoGrid.unmask();
            }
        };
        dataService.findTopicsTree(currentSession.getSelectedAccount().getId(), topicsCallback);
        topicInfoGrid = new TreeGrid<GwtTopic>(store, new ColumnModel(configs));
        topicInfoGrid.setBorders(false);
        topicInfoGrid.setStateful(false);
        topicInfoGrid.setLoadMask(true);
        topicInfoGrid.mask("Loading");
        topicInfoGrid.setStripeRows(true);
        topicInfoGrid.getView().setAutoFill(true);
        topicInfoGrid.getView().setEmptyText(MSGS.topicInfoGridEmptyText());
        topicInfoGrid.disableTextSelection(false);
```

So my question is how to make refresh method for TreeGrid like I've done with regular grid.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this after *onSuccess* method:

```
topicInfoGrid.getTreeView().refresh(true);
```

or this if refresh doesnt work

```
 topicInfoGrid.reconfigure(store, cm, treeColumn);
```

Answer (score 0):

TreeGrids have their own loader which is called TreeLoader instead of using the store's loader: https://docs.sencha.com/gxt/3.x/javadoc/com/sencha/gxt/widget/core/client/treegrid/TreeGrid.html#setTreeLoader(com.sencha.gxt.data.shared.loader.TreeLoader)